# Spring ClassPathRessource get wrong path under eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use `new ClassPathResource("myFolder")` to get some files from this folder "myFolder".

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("myFolder").getFile();
```

This returns file path  my-project\build\**eclipse**\test\myFolder instead of my-project\build\test\myFolder

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a classpath issue in eclipse. The result that you're getting is like that because eclipse does it's own voodoo when youre building and running the application.

Check your classpath in eclipse (and also in the Run Configurations).